# Convert Long.MAX_VALUE to Float

Tags: java, binary, bit

I am was having fun messing around by converting Integer to Float, Float to Long, Long to Int then I got confused by this behavior below.

When I convert a String `s` representing `Long.MAX_VALUE` (63 1s) I got a `NumberFormatException` which was expected. because `Long` is 64 bits and `Integer` is 32 bits so there are extra 31 1s. (This is my guess maybe is another reason please correct me if I am wrong)

However I am not sure why I did not get a `NumberFormatException` when converting `Long` to `Float`. `Long` again is 64 bits and `Float` is 32 bits just like `Integer`. I know bits are interpreted differently as `Float`(IEEE 754 floating-point "single format" bit layout) but what happened to all the other extra 31 bits? I am really lost here....

furthermore how do I get 9.223372E18 which is `1011111000000000000000000000000` bit string? where are those 0s from?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = String.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE); 
    print(s); //prints 9223372036854775807
    print(Long.toBinaryString(Long.MAX_VALUE)); //prints 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
    //Integer.valueOf(s) this throws NumberFormatException because Long is 64 bits and Integer is 32 so s is too large to be an Integer
    print(Float.valueOf(s)); //prints 9.223372E18 Why no NumberFormatException? and how did it result 9.223372E18?

    float f = Float.valueOf(s);
    int intBits = Float.floatToIntBits(f); 
    print(Integer.toBinaryString(intBits)); //1011111000000000000000000000000 How come? s was a String of 1s now there are 0s?
}

public static <T> void print(T arg){
    System.out.println(arg);
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you take the time to read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's confirm for you that the conversion was correct.

[`Long.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE) is 9223372036854775807 (19 digits).  As you can see, the value is approximately what you printed: `9.223372E18`.

The precision of a `long` is always `1`.  However, the precision of a `float` depends on the magnitude of the number.

In a [IEEE single-precision floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), which `float` is, there are only 24 bits of precision in the mantissa, or "fraction" part of the storage.  So the actual value represented by the `float` is an approximation to the actual value off `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

#### Float.floatToIntBits

As you've figured out, the [`Float.floatToIntBits`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits-float-) method yields different bits than the original `long` bit representation.

> Returns a representation of the specified floating-point value according to the IEEE 754 floating-point "single format" bit layout.
>   Bit 31 (the bit that is selected by the mask 0x80000000) represents the sign of the floating-point number. Bits 30-23 (the bits that are selected by the mask 0x7f800000) represent the exponent. Bits 22-0 (the bits that are selected by the mask 0x007fffff) represent the significand (sometimes called the mantissa) of the floating-point number.

(snip)

> **Returns**:
>   the bits that represent the floating-point number.

This method doesn't convert it the *value* to an `int`, it only gives the bit representation of the `float` that happens to be stored in an `int`.  The value represented by this `int` is *not* expected to be the same value as the `float`.

#### The conversion

Those zeroes are the mantissa of the floating point number.  The actual conversion of `long` to `float` involves finding the sign for the most significant bit, finding the magnitude of the value to establish the exponent, and converting the rest of the value into the mantissa.

Because the precision of a `float` at the scale of `Long.MAX_VALUE` is limited, some precision is lost.  The end result is that the `float` value is rounded up slightly.  Because `Long.MAX_VALUE` is 1 short of a power of 2, the round up yields a power of 2, which shows up as all zeros in the mantissa.

You can see the precision of a floating-point value at the scale of a number with [`Math.ulp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp-float-) (unit in last place).

```
Math.ulp(f)
```

which yields

```
1.09951163E12
```

As you can see, the difference is quite large for a `float` for `Long.MAX_VALUE`.  (The ulp for the corresponding `double` is `2048.0`.  Large, but much smaller than the ulp for `float` here.)  But it's in line with what is expected for a value of almost 10<sup>19</sup> -- about 7 digits of precision for a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding `print(Float.valueOf(s)); //prints 9.223372E18 Why no NumberFormatException? and how did it result 9.223372E18?`:**

Floats are represented differently. The number in question is in the range of Float, according to [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3).

Exact conversion, including rounding, is described in [The JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))

**Regarding `print(Integer.toBinaryString(intBits)); //1011111000000000000000000000000 How come? s was a String of 1s now there are 0s?':**

`Float.floatToIntBits(f)` does not return "the same number as integer".
Its semantic is described in [The JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits(float))

Comment: thanks but I am aware floats are represented differently as I stated in the question. I am asking the how the underlying mechanism of converting long to float in java

Comment: You passed a String which represent a valid float. Why would you get NumberFormatException? As for exact implementation, decompile Float.class.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the JavaDoc description, which explicitly state that rounding is part of the conversion, and it being required is not considered "illegal".

Answer (score 0):

A `float` is represented on four bytes (32 bits), a `long` is represented on 8 bytes (64 bits). When you convert a `long` to a `float`, you lose half of your data, as you cannot put 64 bits into 32 bits. This is the reason you have lost a lot of bits.

`float` uses a 23 bit mantissa, so integers bigger than 2^23 will be truncated.

This is why you are able to cast and the cast has the result it has.